# Display information from bluetooth to html5 app?

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth

I am currently working on an HTML5 web app, and I'm trying to display information from a bluetooth LE device. For example, I have a bluetooth device with a single button that acts as a counter. Every time you press the button, the value of the counter increases by 1. Is it possible to display the current value of the counter on my web app? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

take a look at those links:

- js library (not sure if it will good work standalone, without phonegap etc.)
  https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble

Overview of bluetooth, Getting Started

https://evothings.com/ble-app-development-explained/